# how to get information of a point when that point is touched in coreplot?

Tags: iphone, core-plot

I'm working in scattered plot of core plot. when I touch any drawn point in that graph,I need to display some information related to that touched point.

How can I achieve that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

these delegate methods helped me.

```
-(BOOL)plotSpace:(CPTXYPlotSpace *)space shouldHandlePointingDeviceUpEvent:(id)event atPoint:(CGPoint)point{
 NSLog(@"point.x=%lf,point.y=%lf",point.x,point.y);
 return YES;
}

-(BOOL)plotSpace:(CPTXYPlotSpace *)space shouldHandlePointingDeviceCancelledEvent:(id)event{
 //NSLog(@"point.x=%lf,point.y=%lf",point.x,point.y);
 return YES;
}

 -(BOOL)plotSpace:(CPTXYPlotSpace *)space shouldHandlePointingDeviceDownEvent:(id)event atPoint:(CGPoint)point{
 NSLog(@"point.x=%lf,point.y=%lf",point.x,point.y);
 return YES;
}

-(BOOL)plotSpace:(CPTXYPlotSpace *)space shouldHandlePointingDeviceDraggedEvent:(id)event atPoint:(CGPoint)point{
 NSLog(@"point.x=%lf,point.y=%lf",point.x,point.y);
 return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The example apps included with Core Plot show several different ways to do this. In the Plot Gallery app, look at the gradient scatter plot or simple scatter plot. The Mac version of CPTTestApp has a point selection demo that shows one way to draw a crosshairs over the selected point instead of a label.